# do we need to write the dataframe name several times when we refer to different columns in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This should be a quite basic question but I haven't found anything, or maybe it's simply not feasible.

I have a Python Pandas dataframe df having columns A, B, C, I want to create a new column D like this, `df['D'] = df['A']+df['B']*df['C']`, my question is do I have to write "df" four times like this? as they are in the same dataframe, is there an easy way to only write "df" once?

something like:

```
df['D'] = ['A']+['B']*['C']
```

Comment: What are in A/B/C?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: this could create ambiguity. For e.g... in your example, the syntax is the same even for similar operation on a list.

Comment: Call sum on the dataframe selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) that is quite nice for this kind of things:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]})

out = df.eval('D = A+B*C')
```

Or to modify in place:

```
df['D'] = df.eval('A+B*C')
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C   D
0  1  4  7  29
1  2  5  8  42
2  3  6  9  57
```